# What is the probability that a 5-card poker hand contains 3 of a kind?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I tried searching on the net and it shows an answer of
$\frac{ \binom{13}{1} \times \binom{4}{3} \times \binom{12}{2} \times \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{4}{1} }{ \binom{52}{5} }$

Why is it not the same as:
$\frac{ \binom{13}{1} \times \binom{4}{3} \times \binom{48}{1} \times \binom{44}{1}}{ \binom{52}{5} }$

This answer seems to be doubled of the correct answer based on the net.

I also tried different approach and it resulted as this one which is also doubled of the correct answer based on the net.

$\frac{\binom{13}{1} \times \binom{4}{3} \times \binom{12}{1} \times \binom{11}{1} \times \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{4}{1} }{\binom{52}{5}}$

Answer (score 1):

It is not $$\frac {\binom{13}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{3}\cdot\binom{48}{1}\cdot\binom{44}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$ because you are considering the order of the last two selected cards say $A$ and $B$. In other words, you are counting every pair $\{A,B\}$ twice: as $(A,B)$ and $(B,A)$.

Just divide by two and you will obtain the correct result.

Comment: What do you mean by "you are considering the order of the last two selected cards"? Thank you.

Comment: @labyrinthdeux See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say our 3-of-a-kind is made of 5s. When you say " $\binom{48}{1} \times \binom{44}{1}$ " , what you mean is "pick a card that isn't a $5$" (say, a $6$), and then "pick a card that isn't a $5$ or $6$".

The problem is that this counts every pair twice: if your final cards are $(4,7)$ then you count $(7,4)$ a separate time.

To get around this, select two cards $\binom{12}{2}$ and two suits $\binom{4}{1}^2$.